# Computing Sectional Curvature on Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

For a pair of $(X,Y)$ of linearly independent vectors in $T_pM$, $p\in M$, the sectional curvature is defined as

$$K_p(X,Y)=\frac{<R(X,Y)Y,X>}{|X|^2 |Y|^2 - <X,Y>^2}$$

The problem I'm looking at now asks us to compute the same on the half-plane $\mathbb{H} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}|y>0\}$ with the metric $g= 1/y^2(dx^2 + dy^2)$ (and hence show that it is the constant $-1$). The provided solution has an equality that I don't understand:

$$K(\partial_1, \partial_2) = \frac{<R(\partial_1,\partial_2)\partial_2,\partial_1>}{(1/y^2)(1/y^2) - 0} = y^4\frac{1}{y^2}R^2_{112}$$

How is this last equality justified? Namely, I want to understand how the author arrived at this particular set of indices for $R$. I see that the metric is involved because of the inner product, but the details escape me. A breakdown of the steps would be much appreciated!

Comment: @TylerHG It could well be. As I said, I really have no idea how to arrive at that equality, so this could be an error in the solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $E_1 =\partial_x,\ E_2=\partial_y$ are coordinate vector field From this $e_1=y\partial_x,\ e_2=y\partial_y$ are orthonormal vector fields.

$${\rm sec}\ (e_1,e_2)=R(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_1)=\frac{R(E_1,E_2,E_2,E_1)}{ (E_1,E_1)(E_2,E_2)-(E_1,E_2)^2}$$ $$ = \frac{ R_{1221}}{ 1/y^4} = 
y^4 R_{122}^k g_{k1} =y^2 R_{122}^1 $$

(Here index is wrt coordinate vector field)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: Looking over this again, I just have a quick follow-up question: is it true that $R(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_1) = R (y\partial_x , y \partial_y , y \partial_y, y \partial_x) = y^4 R_{1221}$?

Comment: $R_{1221}:= R(E_1,E_2,E_2,E_1)$ Yes It is true